# Render alert component inside try catch react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, formik

I had an issue and tried to solve it, and it took me an hour, I need to show an alert component after the user sent the request successfully. If it is not successful I want to render a component to user, but i tried make this inside a try catch as if it were browser alert.

bellow is my code try catch(i use Redux and formik)

```
  const formik = useFormik({
    initialValues: {
      email: "",
      password: "",
    },
    validationSchema: validationSchema,
    onSubmit: async (values) => {
      dispatch(loginPending());
      try {
        const res = await login(values);
        dispatch(loginSuccess(res));
        dispatch(getUserSuccess(res));
        navigate("/dashboard");
      } catch (err) {
        dispatch(loginFailure(err));
        return alert("Login failed") // here i need render my component <AlertCard/>
      }
    },
  });
```

i need change browser alert to my component AlertCard but i don't know how i make this.

Comment: You wouldn't "render a component" in this context.  You'd dispatch a state update here.  In your component you would use the current state to determine what to render or not render.  So you might have some state value called "isShowingAlertCard" and you'd update that value here.  Then in the component that shows the `<AlertCard/>` you'd check that state value to determine whether or not to show that element.

Answer (score -1):

I think these two post should give you an idea,

[to render a component when response fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59572676/how-to-find-display-error-message-from-api-in-reactjs)

[error handling in react](https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/07/26/error-handling-in-react-16.html)

Comment: This is more of a comment then an answer.  The community appreciates the attempt to help, but answers which are nothing more than links to other questions/answers are considered very low quality.  Please refer to [How To Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for more information.